# How to configure DNS for Services and Pods in Kubernetes?

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes

I have been going through the [K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) on DNS for Services and Pods. The main task that I want to resolve is my K8s deployment has `NodePort` as service type. Meaning, I use the external IP addresses from the nodes to expose the service to the Internet. When I do this, my IP address is getting exposed and would rather prefer to have a hostname [ a DNS name]. Going through the documentation linked above, I do not understand much of the concepts owing to that fact that I'm new to K8s.

I have set-up Ingress Controller from NGINX for Bare Metal K8s because my cloud provider does not provide load balancing service.

So my question is:
How do I set-up an ExternalDNS in my K8s cluster?

For reference purposes, these are my resources inside the K8s cluster.

```
Namespaces
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   3d12h
ingress-nginx     Active   5h53m
kube-node-lease   Active   3d12h
kube-public       Active   3d12h
kube-system       Active   3d12h
```

Basically, I have all my deployments inside the `default` namespace.

```
kubectl get all -n default

 NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-docker-cc749b757-qfctr   1/1     Running   0          70m

NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/hello-docker   NodePort    10.xxx.xxx.xxx   <none>        3000:30072/TCP   70m
service/kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.xxx.xxx.xxx   <none>        443/TCP          3d12h

NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/hello-docker   1/1     1            1           70m

NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/hello-docker-cc749b757   1         1         1       70m
```

And this is the manifest file I have for service and deployment of `hello-docker` app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
 name: hello-docker 
 labels:   
   app: hello-docker
spec: 
 type: NodePort
 ports:
 - port: 3000
   targetPort: 8000
   protocol: TCP
   name: http
 selector:
   app: hello-docker

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-docker
  labels:
    app: hello-docker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-docker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-docker
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
      containers:
      - name: hello-docker
        image: sebastian/hello-docker:1.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
```

Any feedbacks and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: @MikolajS. I have used from a cloud provider. They have tutorial for initial K8s set-up with Ansible and Terraform but do not have LB service. With regard to the version, it is v1.21

Comment: Do you have ready IP node and want to write a domain name - if so you should do it outside of kubernetes - depends of your procider - for example [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/).

Comment: Hello @Sebastian. Any updates?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, nothing interesting, actually. To make it work, I set-up a Cloudflare Tunnel ( aka Argo Tunnel) which routes the traffic via ingress controller. The tunnel needs to be kept alive, so I made the tunnel to run through a VM instance in cloud. Now, the problem is I can access my DNS hostname but can't prevent the direct IP access.

Comment: If you made it work consider adding your solution as an answer and create new question with current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this work by creating a Cloudflare Tunnel (previously called Argo Tunnel).
A complete configuration documentation on the tunnel can be found [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/many-cfd-one-tunnel). I hope someone with similar issue finds this useful.